# Fluent validation allow empty or value with structure

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a sort prop that can be empty or values like:

```
sort=""
sort=["name","desc"]
sort=["name","asc"]


RuleFor(r => r.Sort)
                .NotEmpty()
                .When(nr => nr.Contains("name"))
                .WithMessage("Invalid Sort");
```

How to allow empty, and non empty with contains a string?

Comment: What type are you using for `r.Sort`? Is it `string`? Is it `IEnumerable<string>`? Something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just specify a custom rule. Assuming `Sort` is of `string[]`:

```
RuleFor(r => r.Sort)
    .NotNull()
    .Must(x => x.Length == 0 || (x.Length == 2 && x[0] == "name" && 
        (x[1] == "desc" || x[1] == "asc")))
    .WithMessage(...);
```

And if you need to reuse this logic,  just use a custom rule builder [as explained here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html).